Función onClick se pierde cuando actualizo los renglones de una tabla HTML
Buen día.
Tengo un tabla en HTML la cuál debe marcar el renglón seleccionado por el usuario. Cuando ingreso a la página, veo que la tabla con datos hace la función de marcar el renglón al que el usuario hace clic en él. Pero cuando actualizo los datos de la tabla usando jQuery, el evento onClick se pierde y deja de funcionar.
Les dejo el código de ejemplo para que vean de qué hablo.
Explicación del ejemplo: Al ejecutar el ejemplo, hagan clic sobre algún renglón de la tabla y verán cómo se marca ese renglón. Luego, hagan clic en el botón Actualizar y verán que los renglones de la tabla cambian, y a partir de ahí, ya no se puede seleccionar ningún renglón.
Muchas gracias!


    $(function () {
        $("#TblBody").children("tr").click(function (event) {
            if (!$(this).hasClass("row-selected")) {
                FnClearSelected();
                $(this).addClass("row-selected");
            }
        });

        function FnClearSelected() {
            $(".row-selected").each(function (index, element) {
                $(element).removeClass("row-selected");
            })
        }
    })
    
    function FnAddRows() {
        var StrTabla = "TblTabla", StrTableBody = "TblBody";
        var TblResults = document.getElementById(StrTableBody);
        var oRow = "";

        FnClearTable(StrTabla);

        
        var StrRow = "<tr><td>Fulano</td><td>Fulana</td></tr>";
        StrRow += "<tr><td>Mengano</td><td>Mengana</td></tr>";

        TblResults.innerHTML += StrRow;
    }
    
    function FnClearTable(IdTabla) {

        var oTable = document.getElementById(IdTabla);
        var RowCount = oTable.rows.length;

        while (--RowCount) {
            oTable.deleteRow(RowCount);
        }

    }
    .row-selected {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row mb-2">
      <div class="col-12 mt-2">
          <div class="d-flex">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary ms-1" onclick="FnAddRows()">Actualizar</button>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
          <table id="TblTabla" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-bordered">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>Firstname</th>
                      <th>Lastname</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody id="TblBody">
                  <tr>
                      <td>John</td>
                      <td>Doe</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>Amy</td>
                      <td>Jhonson</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>Sam</td>
                      <td>Smith</td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>




La idea de children es seleccionar las filas de la tabla hijas de #TblBody.
Cuando se añaden nuevas filas de forma dinámica usando la function FnAddRows(), las nuevas filas no son hijas de #TblBody y por ese motivo el evento no va a funcionar como lo hizo la primera vez.
En este caso, usa api.jquery.com/click ya que, aunque las filas hijas no sean hijas del elemento padre, el listener capturará cualquier clic dentro de #TblBody y al seleccionar tanto las filas iniciales como las nuevas filas añadidas de forma dinámica tendrá el mismo efecto.


$(function () {
  $("#TblBody").on("click", "tr", function (event) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("row-selected")) {
      FnClearSelected(); 
      
    } else {
      FnClearSelected(); 
      $(this).addClass("row-selected");
    }
  });
  
          function FnClearSelected() {
            $(".row-selected").each(function (index, element) {
                $(element).removeClass("row-selected");
            })
        }
    })
    
    function FnAddRows() {
        var StrTabla = "TblTabla", StrTableBody = "TblBody";
        var TblResults = document.getElementById(StrTableBody);
        var oRow = "";

        FnClearTable(StrTabla);

        
        var StrRow = "<tr><td>Fulano</td><td>Fulana</td></tr>";
        StrRow += "<tr><td>Mengano</td><td>Mengana</td></tr>";

        TblResults.innerHTML += StrRow;
    }
    
    function FnClearTable(IdTabla) {

        var oTable = document.getElementById(IdTabla);
        var RowCount = oTable.rows.length;

        while (--RowCount) {
            oTable.deleteRow(RowCount);
        }

    }
    .row-selected {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row mb-2">
      <div class="col-12 mt-2">
          <div class="d-flex">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary ms-1" onclick="FnAddRows()">Actualizar</button>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
          <table id="TblTabla" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-bordered">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>Firstname</th>
                      <th>Lastname</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody id="TblBody">
                  <tr>
                      <td>John</td>
                      <td>Doe</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>Amy</td>
                      <td>Jhonson</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>Sam</td>
                      <td>Smith</td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>




Muchas gracias Cardosource... se ve muy bien, la voy a implementar. Había encontrado un workaround en el cual, la función ´FnAddRows()´ invocaba a una nueva función que hacía la asignación de la clase para que, como bien comentas, se heredara a los nuevos hijos de la Tbody. Ésta solución que propones suena mejor, la pongo en práctica y te comento. Muchas gracias!

Genial... va perfecto! Muchas gracias Cardosource! Saludos!

Sólo me gustaría agrega un comentario, para que no quede ambiguo el tema. Me parece entender que, el problema no es que las nuevas filas añadidas no sean hijas del tbody, de hecho lo son por que las agrego a ese nivel. Creo que el problema es que la función click, invocada desde el children, aplica la propiedad a los que son hijos en el momento en que se invoca, los nuevos hijos no estaban cuando se asignó la propiedad y, por eso funcionó el WorkAround. La solución que me brindaste, al parecer persiste incluso para los hijos nuevos, pues se aplica al TBody.
